# Load webviews and take snapshots programmatically to display in collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uicollectionview

I currently am loading a `collectionView` of `WebViews` which is ok, but doesn't work great, for example ads often obscure the content of the `webview`.  What I'd like to do is programmatically load the `webview` and take a snapshot of it, then reload the `collectionView` with the images as opposed to the `WebViews` themselves?

```
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ResultsCollectionViewCell

        if let url = Urls?[indexPath.row] {
            self.activityIN.stopAnimating()
            self.progressLabel.removeFromSuperview()
            cell.webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
        }


        return cell
    }
```

Comment: `Urls` should be lowercased if it is not a class and only an array variable

Answer (score 0):

- create 2 cells - one with a webview, and one with a imageview
- on reload decide if there still exists an screenshot and display the cell with imageview
- in the webview use a custom webview which saves after finished loading takes a snapshot, save the screenshot, add screenshot name to the Urls collection, then remove the webview and replace it with a imageview

Comment: Thanks I'm having a hard time figuring out how to load a webview and take a screenshot of it all programmatically though

Comment: for taking a screenshot from webview you will find many answers here at SO